# How to add legend to sequence sunburst chart of d3js for my own data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[Legend Color not matching Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWd5Q.png) I am Working on the d3js sequence sunburst chart.

My Sample Data is:

```
Shift-Mode-Machineid,MachineDuration
DayShift-auto-1091,1
DayShift-auto-1100,5
DayShift-auto-1100,117
DayShift-manual-1111,4
DayShift-manual-1112,6
DayShift-manual-1120,43
NightShift-auto-1150,9
NightShift-auto-1150,85
NightShift-auto-1150,6
NightShift-manual-1120,16
NightShift-manual-1120,1
NightShift-manual-1120,4
```

Please suggest how to match the legend color and the chart color. The text inside the legend is perfect but the color is a mismatch. I have to put correct colors. Please help.

```
  // Dimensions of sunburst.[Screenshot of wrong color in legend][1]
var width = 750;
var height = 600;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// Mapping of step names to colors.
var colors = {};
var color = d3.scale.category20b();
/*{
  "home": "#5687d1",
  "product": "#7b615c",
  "search": "#de783b",
  "account": "#6ab975",
  "other": "#a173d1",
  "end": "#bbbbbb"
}*/;

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0; 

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

// Use d3.text and d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
// row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.
d3.text("Data.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
/*After getting proper json, we are making colors variable to hold our data keys
*/
  json.children.forEach(function(root, ind){
      colors[root.name]=color(ind);
  });

  createVisualization(json);
});

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  drawLegend();
  d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.parent ? d : d.children).name); })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover);

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 };

// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {

  var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
  var percentageString = percentage + "%";
  if (percentage < 0.1) {
    percentageString = "< 0.1%";
  }

  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(percentageString);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
     // .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.parent ? d : d.children).name); });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", d3.keys(colors).length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.entries(colors))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
}

function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}

// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how 
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some analysis, I could suggest you below code, try it once.

```
// Dimensions of sunburst.
var width = 750;
var height = 600;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// Mapping of step names to colors.
var colors = {};/*{
  "home": "#5687d1",
  "product": "#7b615c",
  "search": "#de783b",
  "account": "#6ab975",
  "other": "#a173d1",
  "end": "#bbbbbb"
}*/;

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0; 

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

// Use d3.text and d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
// row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.
d3.text("visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
/*After getting proper json, we are making colors variable to hold our data keys
*/
  json.children.forEach(function(root, ind){
      colors[root.name]=color(root.name); //Changed ind to root.name
  });

  createVisualization(json);
});

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  drawLegend();
  d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover);

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 };

// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {

  var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
  var percentageString = percentage + "%";
  if (percentage < 0.1) {
    percentageString = "< 0.1%";
  }

  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(percentageString);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", d3.keys(colors).length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.entries(colors))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
}

function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}

// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how 
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
};
```

Try this code n tell me.
We need to change

```
json.children.forEach(function(root, ind){
          colors[root.name]=color(ind); //Changed ind to root.name
      });
```

so that

```
json.children.forEach(function(root, ind){
          colors[root.name]=color(root.name);
      });
```

Hope this is causing colors not to match.
Try n tell me now.

Comment: I have updated my code and the screenshot. The one you have given is almost done, just that the color of legend and the chart is not matching. Please tell me the solution. Check my updated code and the screenshot above in the question I have asked.

Comment: @aishwaryasrivastava I've updated my answer, check n tell me.

Comment: Excellent! It Worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot :) :)

Comment: One thing more, If I want to add the second layer also to my legend what should be added? Means Along with day shift, night shift legend I also want to add  in the same legend for Auto and Manual which is my second layer in the chart (children I guess).

Comment: @ mkaran. Please help for the above question regarding adding legend for two layers of the sequence sunburst chart.

Comment: @aishwaryasrivastava To add legends for inner layer, you have to share your data(Few records), so that we can work on it and give you my best.

Comment: Hi, I have added my sample data in my question above.(The one I had asked for first time) Please check and let me know how to add legend for inner layer. Some more changes might be required to be done to your code for achieving this.

Comment: @ saikiran.vsk Hi, I have dont it. Thanks for your concern. I just needed to add json.children[0].children.forEach(function(root)){} for adding for inner layer. Thanks

Comment: `/*After getting proper json, we are making colors variable to hold our data keys
*/

  json.children.forEach(function(root, ind){
      colors[root.name]=color(root.name); //Changed ind to root.name
 console.log(root);
 if(root.children.length){
  root.children.forEach(function(ch){
   colors[ch.name]=color(ch.name);
   if(ch.children.length){
    ch.children.forEach(function(ch1){
     colors[ch1.name]=color(ch1.name);
    });
   }
  });
 }
  });`